# how to do closest point query using OpenVDB?

Tags: c++, vector, openvdb

First, How to find closest point using openvdb?

Second, If `ClosestSurfacePoint` is right way to do that, how to use it?

I read paper about ICP using OpenVDB for faster NNS.

(http://www.pmavridis.com/research/efficient_sparse_icp/)

The author says that he got advance in speed by using openvdb  for NNS.

And some other people achieved same thing in similar way.

So, I wanted to try that myself.

After several trying, i finally succeeded in compiling.

However, i am little bit confused.

In my point of view(after reading lots of docs including online cookbook) sampler seemed to do that

so, i tried these examples.

```
GridType::ConstAccessor accessor = grid.getConstAccessor();
GridType::ValueType v0 = openvdb::tools::PointSampler::sample(accessor, ijk);
GridType::ValueType v1 = openvdb::tools::BoxSampler::sample(accessor, ijk);
GridType::ValueType v2 = openvdb::tools::QuadraticSampler::sample(accessor, ijk);
```

I did things as described below

object: find point   in grid  closest to query point(ijk)

1. Create points(or load points) and convert into vec3d format
2. make point index grid.
3. set query point(ijk)
4. set accessor of index grid
5. function call of point sampler()

But, these examples show 0 or 1.

If, it finds exact same position, it return 1.
If not, 0.

Probably, this pointsampler is not what i looking for.

Try in other way.

Other candidates are

```
 ClosestSurfacePoint, ClosestPointProjector.
```

i tried the codes written in below
it's similar as betajippity's work
https://github.com/betajippity/Ariel/blob/master/src/grid/levelset.cpp

but it makes error because of vector

```
std::vector<openvdb::Vec3s> positions = {
        { 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 2, 1 },
        { 2, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 1 },
        { 100, 100, 100 },
        { 100, 101, 100 }
    };

myPointList pointlist(positions);

const float voxelSize(1.0);
openvdb::math::Transform::Ptr transform(openvdb::math::Transform::createLinearTransform(voxelSize));

openvdb::tools::PointIndexGrid::Ptr vdbgrid =
    openvdb::tools::createPointIndexGrid<openvdb::tools::PointIndexGrid>(pointlist, *transform);

openvdb::FloatGrid vdbgrid;


openvdb::util::NullInterrupter n;
std::vector<float> distances;


openvdb::tools::ClosestSurfacePoint<openvdb::tools::PointIndexGrid> csp;

csp.initialize(*vdbgrid, 0.0f, &n);
```

The last line

```
csp.initialize(*vdbgrid, 0.0f, &n);
```

Causes Debug Assertion failed.

```
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vector
Line: 72

Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable
```

I have no idea how to deal with these things.

Because I cannot modify openvdb's inside. I just called function and it makes error :(

If you have any idea for this, please help.

Again, Questions are..

How to find closest point using openvdb?

If `ClosestSurfacePoint` is right way to do that, how to use it?

I really appreciate you in advance.

Comment: I think you missed your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: @pingul thanks, i edited post.  First, how to find closest point using openvdb. If ClosestSurfacePoint is right way to do that, how to use it?

Comment: You should only need a `PointIndexGrid`. Use the grid to get the LeafNode where your point is, and then iterate over all the points in the LeafNode to find which one is the closest.

Comment: @pingul Thans for comment, i will try that.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: @pingul actually, i decided to try another method. because if i traverse all of leaf nodes its just same as naive sequential traverse.   it looks like put points into kdtree and convert into array then, traverse. I need to look around openvdb api and docs more time. Anyway thanks,

Comment: maybe you're right, but i need to figure out fastest way and reason for that.

Comment: You don't traverse all the leaf nodes -- you traverse all the voxels and particle in 1 leaf node.

Comment: The last statement is half-true. You would probably need to expand the search radius somewhat (if you look for at a coordinate close to the edge of a leaf, the closest point might be in a nearby leaf, so you might have to increase the search radius). For your small example you will definitely not see a speedup, but it should go significantly faster than a normal traverse of the array when you start increasing the number of points. Also, note that OpenVDB since 1 week supports points internally: https://github.com/dneg/openvdb_points_dev

Comment: @pingul oh,, i see. i misunderstood your previous comment. i will try again. Thanks for help.

Comment: And... because of environmental constraints(VS2013) i can not build 4.0, i need to use 3.2 instead. so.. before usage of openvdb points, i have to build it separately. Too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from OpenVDB points developer.

---

It's a good question,
 I'll attempt to answer this.

In short, yes and no. 
OpenVDB Points is an ideal base data structure for doing nearest neighbor search as it is already spatially organised,

however we have not yet provided any high-level APIs to do for this for you so you would have to write much of the algorithm yourself.

Due to the spatial nature of the grid, 
it's relatively simple and very fast to do a nearest neighbor search where you have a "maximum radius" in which to search that isn't too large as you can tune the size of your voxels to match this radius and maximise performance.

It is much more challenging to perform an arbitrary-distance nearest neighbor search, where I suggest you'll find it hard to get decent performance out of the data structure without also writing a supporting framework (such as a kd-tree).

We have attempted nearest-neighbor algorithms though, 
so if I haven't put you off with that summary, we would be happy to point you in the right direction here regarding an implementation. :)

Thanks,
Dan

---